# Run user space application in kernel without user_mode_helper function

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I want to execute a user space application from Linux kernel ,but without using user_mode_helper function api.
Found that sys_execv() can be used to run user space app from kernel ,any idea about it?

Comment: Why not? You can't call syscalls directly from the kernel. You'll have to implement `user_mode_helper` pretty much.

Comment: Means i  have not option and I must have to use user_mode_helper function API to call my executable from kernel.?